# Not able to make regular expression for pattern "1#23#567#3#98" in PHP

Tags: php, regex

We are developing a small module for one of our clients. In this module, we have to validate input values with a predefined pattern. So, we are using a regular expression to achieve this.

We are trying to create a regular expression but we have failed each time.

Values are allowed in the format of:

**1#4#5#654#12....**

where 0<=n<=100000000000

Some examples of input strings are given below:

1#23#567#3#98 - Valid string

#1#45#21#4# - Invalid

67##78#56#09# - Invalid

0#0#0 - Valid

Only positive numbers and the hash sign are allowed in the above values. The string should start and end with a number. Only one hash is allowed between two numbers. There are no restrictions for the length of the string.

Can anyone please share the regular expression which would match valid strings?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd say this should do: `\d+(#\d+)*`

Comment: Is it `numbers#ID#numbers` and you want to capture the `ID`? or just any number of `#numers` after the beginning of the string?

Answer (score 1):

```
^(10{11}|\d{1,11})(#(10{11}|\d{1,11}))+$
```

This should ensure the pattern does not match any numbers that exceed One Hundred Billion.

Answer (score 0):

```
$strings = array(
    '67##78#56#09#32',
    '1#23#567#3#98',
    '#1#45#21#4#',
    '67##78#56#09#',
    '0#0#0'
);

$regex = '/^\d+(#\d+)*$/';

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    var_dump(preg_match($regex, $string));
}
```

The output would be:

```
int(0) int(1) int(0) int(0) int(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to restrict the values between 0 and 100bln, you can use the `(10{11}|\d{1,11})` grouping (same as @Flosculus). Next, you can just recurse this *subpattern* with the help of `\g<1>` to make the pattern shorter (in PCRE only).

Thus, if you allow digit-only input, use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/pT6oC1/1):

```
^(10{11}|\d{1,11})(?:#\g<1>)*$
                            ^
```

Or if there must be at least one hash, use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/pT6oC1/2):

```
^(10{11}|\d{1,11})(?:#\g<1>)+$
                            ^
```

PHP demo:

```
$re = '/^(10{11}|\d{1,11})(?:#\g<1>)+$/'; 
$str = array("1#23#567#3#98", "0#0#0", "#1#45#21#4#", "67##78#56#09#"); 
$n = preg_grep($re, $str);
print_r($n);
```

Returns:

```
[0] => 1#23#567#3#98
[1] => 0#0#0
```

Comment: `\g<1>`, is that how you reference a previous group?

Comment: No, `\g<1>` references the first capturing group *subpattern* (unlike a backreference `\1` that would reference the Group 1 *value*).